# O que é uma "água-furtada"?

Tags: significado, expressões, diferenças-transatlânticas

A única vez em que ouvi essa expressão foi na música "um craveiro numa água-furtada, cheira bem, cheira a Lisboa..."  Em ptBR nunca ouvi ninguem falar.  Água-furtada, se entendido literalmente soa como "uma água roubada", mas percebi imediatamente que o significado era outro.  Procurei a palavra em alguns dicionários online e fiquei mais confuso ainda porque encontrei as seguintes definições:

> - "água-furtada" —  Vão entre as tesouras do telhado. Ângulo do telhado por onde correm as águas pluviais. Espécie de sótão. É uma parte do telhado, constituída por uma aresta inclinada delimitada pelo encontro de duas águas que formam um ângulo reentrante, ou seja, é para onde convergem as águas que caem sobre o telhado, por este motivo, também é conhecido por calha ou “rincão”. [Colégio de Arquitetos](http://www.colegiodearquitetos.com.br/dicionario/2009/02/o-que-e-agua-furtada/)
> - águas-furtadas — Último andar de um edifício, entre o telhado e o penúltimo andar, quando as janelas deitam sobre o telhado, geralmente com tetos inclinados. [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/%C3%A1guas-furtadas)
> - "água-furtada" — Vão entre as tesouras do telhado. Ângulo do telhado por onde correm as água pluviais. [Dicionário Eng. Civil](http://www.ecivilnet.com/dicionario/o-que-e-agua-furtada.html)
> - "água-furtada" — Parte do telhado, constituída por uma aresta inclinada delimitada pelo encontro de duas águas que formam um ângulo reentrante, ou seja, é para onde convergem as águas que caem sobre o telhado, por este motivo, também é conhecido por calha ou "rincão". [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81gua-furtada)

**Afinal, o que vem a ser "um craveiro numa água-furtada"?**

Comment: A definição do Priberam tem uma boa foto explicativa.

Comment: @ANeves Não naquilo que aparece aqui para mim online. veja http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/%C3%A1guas-furtadas

Comment: A mim não aparece nada. Mas googlando águas furtadas, imagens, aparecem montes delas. O edifício da Praça Imperial do Rio de Janeiro é um edifício oficial, nobre. As águas furtadas são mais comuns em prédios residenciais.

Comment: @Centaurus sim, tem um link pequeno para http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/images/dplp/%C3%A1guas-furtadas.jpg - com o ícone de uma máquina fotográfica, no fim da frase de definição (depois de "tectos inclinados" [sic]). Pelo menos para mim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pudera! com essas definições até eu desaprendia o que são águas furtadas. As águas-furtadas da canção (substantivo plural, o “água-furtada” da canção é fora da norma) são um espaço de habitação — apartamento independente ou parte de casa —  imediatamente abaixo do telhado, e por isso com teto inclinado; por vezes as paredes são também inclinadas. Um nome equivalente mas menos comum em Portugal é *mansarda*. Como duas imagens valem mais que duas mil palavras:

### Águas-furtadas

[image]
**Águas-furtadas vistas de dentro**

[image: Edifícios com águas-furtadas em Vila Real de Santo António, Algarve]
**Águas-furtadas vistas de fora** (Vila Real de Santo António, Algarve)

No modelo tradicional, as janelas são salientes — deitam sobre o telhado, na linguagem do Priberam — tal como nas duas fotos acima. O “craveiro numa água-furtada” da canção estaria num vaso no parapeito da janela ou pendurado imediatamente abaixo, muito ao gosto dos bairros populares de Lisboa.

O outro significado, ângulo reentrante formado pelo encontro de duas águas (superfícies planas) de um telhado, por onde correm as águas da chuva, não o conhecia, e ao que parece é termo oficial no Brasil também, pois aparece [com foto neste site brasileiro](http://www.fortcalhassorocaba.com.br/servicos.php).

Comment: E já agora, no Brasil são?

Comment: Não sei.  Nunca soube que essas estruturas tivessem um nome.  Talvez alguem aqui saiba.  Já as vi mas não são muito comuns por aqui.  As casas da foto são exemplos de que estilo?   Pombalino?

Comment: Pombalino, exatamente. É em Vila Real de Santo António, cidade mandada construir pelo próprio Marquês.

Comment: Temos muitas construções em estilo Pombalino, mas sem as águas furtadas.  Aquelas pequenas sacadas, chamamos mesmo de "sacadas".  Quando são bem grandes, com vários metros quadrados e com teto, chamamos de varanda ou varandão.

Comment: Em Portugal são muito comuns, deves estar lembrado.

Comment: aqui no RJ  https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pra%C3%A7a_Quinze_de_Novembro_(Rio_de_Janeiro)#/media/File:Pca_xv_paco_imperial.JPG

Answer (score -2):

Estão todos errados ! Água-Furtada ( vivem em águas-furtadas ) significa **sótão**, normalmente com teto inclinado pelo telhado !!!

Comment: Então a Amália Rodrigues cantou sobre um craveiro no sótão!

Comment: "estão todos errados"  além de não ser a forma mais educada de discordar com a resposta de outrem, carece de referências e links.

Comment: @Centaurus, creio que o Paulo não leu ou não compreendeu a minha explicação nem a tua citação do Priberam ("todos errados" não deve ser só a minha resposta), que estão corretas. Não sei se *sótão* é comum no Brasil. *Sótão* pode ser águas-furtadas (dizem os dicionários), mas pelo menos aqui em Portugal tipicamente só partilha com as águas-furtadas o ficar imediatamente abaixo do telhado: sem janelas, acesso ao piso abaixo por alçapão e escada de mão, e quando é usado é para guardar velharias. As águas furtadas são um verdadeiro último piso para habitação, só que com tetos inclinados.

Comment: @Jacinto   Aqui no Rio de Janeiro moramos cada vez menos em casas e mais em apartamentos.  A minha ideia de sótão é a de um andar próximo do telhado, de piso horizontal, com pouco acabamento, o teto costuma ser o próprio telhado,e onde os moradores guardam objetos de pouco uso e tralha velha, ou então não guardam nada.  Meu primo, Tuga da gema, mora em uma casa de vila no Porto com um sótão que ele transformou em escritório.  Eu chamei de sótão e ele pareceu não discordar quanto ao nome.

Comment: @Centaurus, sim o sótão é isso. Mas quando é construído de raiz para habitação, com janelas e isso, chamamos-lhe águas furtadas. Vê aqui [uma por dentro](https://fotos.habitissimo.pt/foto/sala-2o-esq-aguas-furtadas_2164)-- Este é o modelo tradicional, mas agora há umas em que a janela em vez de ser saliente, acompanha o plano do telhado.

Comment: @Jacinto    ´Veja se entendi corretamente:  a figura mostra o que seria o interior de um sótão, não foisse o fato de ter a janela projetada e acabamento para ser um cômodo habitado diariamente. Neste caso chama-se "águas furtadas".   Estou certo ?   Em tempo:  acho que com a janela acompanhando o plano do telhado,  perde um pouco do charme (opinião pessoal).

Comment: @Centaurus, sim, é basicamente isso; não interessa se a janela é projetada ou não (sim, as projetadas são mais charmosas). É claro que quando quando constróis uma casa com águas furtadas de raiz, vais ter alguns cuidados que não seriam necessários se aquilo fosse só um sótão: pé direito suficientemente alto para não andares às cabeçadas no telhado, janelas, acesso por escadas normais, patamar e porta (para sótão bastaria um alçapão).

Comment: Paulo, @Jacinto e demais, como a palavra "sótão" me parece ser mais usada (ao menos no Brasil) que "águas-furtadas", considero uma contribuição relevante mencionar o sinônimo -- mas editei a pergunta, apagando a afirmação incorreta de que todos estariam incorretos. Paulo, você pode reverter minha edição, mas é provavelmente melhor aceitá-la (ou fazer outra equivalente, ou justificar a afirmação), para que sua resposta seja bem recebida (ela acaba de receber um voto negativo, não meu).

Comment: @stafusa, se o entendimento que no Brasil fazem de *sótão* é o que explicou o Centaurus acima (que coincide com o meu entendimento), esta resposta só cria confusão: as águas-furtadas são um espaço destinado a habitação. As recomendações para edição (aparecem à direita na página da edição) incluem "clarify meaning without changing it" e "always respect the original author". Creio que a tua edição vai além disto; claramente melhora a resposta, mas parece-me que te fizeste coautor e não simplesmente editor. O Paulo não se chegou a resgistar, duvido que cá volte.

Comment: @Jacinto Sou ativo no Physics SE há um tempo já e, lá, edições mais severas que a minha são comuns. Isso não significa, é claro, que tenhamos que ter os mesmos critérios aqui, mas serve para mostrar que diferentes interpretações das regras são válidas. Apaguei "Estão todos errados", 3 palavras que não faziam sentido, assim como poderia apagar um irrelevante "Espero que alguém me responda" ou um ofensivo "Vocês são todos idiotas". Mas claro que isso é aberto a discussão, e não ficaria ofendido se alguém desfizesse minha edição.

Comment: @Jacinto No segundo ponto, sobre sótão, tenho um entendimento bem diferente do teu: tanto aqui na Alemanha, quanto nos EUA, quanto no Brasil (onde sótãos na verdade são raros) penso que se entende como está na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B3t%C3%A3o): `Por norma, trata-se de um espaço de difícil acesso e, por isso, aproveitado para acomodar diversos equipamentos de manutenção e de conforto da habitação (p. ex. caixa - d'água, sistemas de climatização, acumuladores fotovoltaicos) ou como área de armazenamento.` Ser usado como área de habitação é a exceção, não a norma.

Comment: @stafusa, estás a fazer uma confusão qualquer. *Sótão* é isso (espaço de acesso difícil, usado, quando é usado, para guardar velharias); *águas-furtadas*, em Portugal, **não** são isso--são um espaço de habitação.

Comment: @Jacinto Ah, sim, se em Portugal é usado apenas para quando o espaço é uma parte normal do prédio, então **não** seria sinônimo de sótão. O ponto é que, nos dicionário que consultei (e.g., [1](https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%A1guas-furtadas), [2](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/%C3%A1guas-furtadas), e [3](http://www.aulete.com.br/%C3%A1gua-furtada)) e nas wikipedias ([en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic) e [pt](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B3t%C3%A3o)), *água-furtada* é colocada como sendo um `sótão com janelas`, ou seja, um caso particular de sótão.

Comment: @stafusa, o artigo da wikipédia é fraco. Ao que parece há quem chame *sótão* às águas-furtadas, mas o inverso -- chamar *águas-furtadas* a um espaço que não seja para habitação -- parece-me que não. Quer o Priberam quer a Infopédia definem, corretamente, *aguas-furtadas* como o "último andar" ('piso, apartamento'), e definem *sótão* como "compartimento".

Comment: @Jacinto O verbete da Wikipedia é só um *stub*, mas os dicionários são melhores: 1) a Infopédia claramente [coloca](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/s%C3%B3t%C3%A3o) *águas-furtadas* como um sinônimo de sótão: `só.tão: 1. compartimento [...] , águas-furtadas` e o Aulete [explicitamente](http://www.aulete.com.br/s%C3%B3t%C3%A3o) afirma que o *sótão* também pode ser para habitação: `(só.tão) 
Arq. 
 
sm.
 
1. Compartimento habitável entre o telhado e o teto de uma casa;` Talvez usar exclusivamente águas-furtadas para sótão habitável seja um regionalismo?

Comment: @stafusa, a Infopédia é o único que faz isso; o Priberam, o Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, o Houaiss, e o Sociedade da Língua Portuguesa, não -- definem *águas-furtadas* exclusivamente como espaço de habitação. Parece-me portanto que se nalgum lado se chama *águas-furtadas* a um espaço não habitável, isso é que será um regionalismo; ou talvez seja descuido na Infopédia. No contexto da pergunta é claramente habitação; quem é que iria pôr um craveiro num sótão fechado?

Comment: @stafusa, a outra coisa. “Olá a todos”, “Cumprimentos”, etc. não diriam nada acerca de *águas-furtadas*, e poem por isso ser retirados. Com “estão todos errados”, o respondente já diz alguma coisa sobre *águas-furtadas* (que todas as definições apresentadas antes estão erradas); ao retirares isso, alteras substantivamente a resposta. É claro que aquilo era absurdo, mas era o que lá estava.

Comment: @Jacinto Tens razão. Fiz o rollback.

Comment: @Jacinto Sobre sótão/águas-furtadas, passei a concordar. Há mais fontes que fazem a distinção não-habitável/habitável (respectivamente) do que que não fazem. Além disso, como essas construções são muito mais comuns na Europa que no Brasil, e também dado o contexto da pergunta, acaba mesmo sendo verdade que dizer apenas "sótão" para explicar "águas-furtadas" é uma má reposta. -1